# Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. error?

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload the file to Azure blob storage using SAS token by angular-azure-blob-service in typescript, I pass the following data to the upload method which is present in the service :

Object:

```
baseUrl: "https://xxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/containername/xx-image.png"
blockSize: 65536
complete: ƒ ()
error: ƒ (err)
file: File {name: "abc-image.png", lastModified: 1502710846384, lastModifiedDate: Mon Aug 14 2017 17:10:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 17605, …}
progress: ƒ (percent)
sasToken: "?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=3whdfgdfzCeW0FSaZvmNfxh%2FdcUEcpjqmR%2BA%2FRlzHq8%3D&st=2019-04-16T12%3A46%3A47Z&se=2019-04-16T12%3A56%3A47Z&sp=w"
```

When i pass the above data, i get the below error :

> error: "`AuthenticationFailed`Server
>   failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature.↵RequestId:85189ba5-c01e-013f-614a-f4a448000000↵Time:2019-04-16T11:53:02.4545120ZSignature did not match. String to sign used was
>   w↵2019-04-16T11:46:46Z↵2019-04-16T11:56:46Z↵/blob/xxxxxx/companylogo/background slider.PNG↵↵↵↵2018-03-28↵↵↵↵↵"
>   headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null,
>   lazyInit: ƒ} message: "Http failure response for
>   https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/containername/background%20slider.PNG?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=JhdFAXD7P0QwyjAhClo9Axry%2FSSLp8POIQx4vJ0vxJ0%3D&st=2019-04-16T11%3A46%3A46Z&se=2019-04-16T11%3A56%3A46Z&sp=w&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw:
>   403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
>   name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 403 statusText: "Server
>   failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
>   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
>   url:
>   "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/containername/background%20slider.PNG?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=JhdFAXD7P0QwyjAhClo9Axry%2FSSLp8POIQx4vJ0vxJ0%3D&st=2019-04-16T11%3A46%3A46Z&se=2019-04-16T11%3A56%3A46Z&sp=w&comp=block&blockid=YmxvY2stMDAwMDAw"
>   **proto**: Object

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass the token in the Authorization header, like the error suggests instead of in the general request.

Comment: since it  authenticates with the SAS token, I don't think it is necessary to pass the access token in the header

Answer (score 0):

Will you take using Azure AD RBAC to uploading blobs to Azure storage into your account? This way will much easier than using SAS token if you just want to uploading files.With this feature , you can access your storage using access token which obtain from Azure AD instead of making up SAS token. For details , pls refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad